# Redirect 301 file extension to non extension

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to remove the all the .php extensions from my urls and 301 redirect them to non extension (/).

All urls ending with .php will become /. For example:

`www.biluthyrning24.se/albanien/hyrbil.php` automatically redirects to

`www.biluthyrning24.se/albanien/hyrbil/`

Is this possible in `.htaccess`?

Thank you for all replies.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually try to do. Please use the `edit` button below your question to fill in more details about your actual situation. What are the incoming requests and what should they be rewritten to? Try to explain what it is you want to do exactly, not how you think you might be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ".htm" The $1 is a variable that holds the match from the group.

Comment: That worked. 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: This worked, however, it also made me unable to access Wordpress control panel. Any idea how I can make exceptions to wordpress files / folders?